# DataTemplateに追加したAppendChildの値を取得、設定したい

Tags: c#, wpf

[C#のWPFでTemplateをコードで作る](https://araramistudio.jimdo.com/2016/12/07/wpf%E3%81%A7template%E3%82%92%E3%82%B3%E3%83%BC%E3%83%89%E3%81%A7%E4%BD%9C%E3%82%8B/)
上記ページを参考にコードでDataTemplateを作り表示されました。

```
FrameworkElementFactory textBlock = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(TextBlock), "TextBlock");
textBlock.SetValue(TextBlock.MarginProperty, new Thickness(5, 5, 5, 5));
textBlock.SetValue(TextBlock.TextProperty, "テキスト本文");

FrameworkElementFactory image = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(Image), "Image");
BitmapImage bitmapImage = new BitmapImage(new Uri(イメージのURL));
imageElement.SetValue(Image.SourceProperty, bitmapImage);

FrameworkElementFactory stackPanel = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(StackPanel), "StackPanel");
stackPanel.AppendChild(textBlock);
stackPanel.AppendChild(image);

DataTemplate template = new DataTemplate();
template.VisualTree = stackPanel;
```

テキスト本文やbitmapImageを変えたい場合、どのようにすべきなのでしょうか？
また、DataTemplateからAppendChildの要素を取得、設定することは可能でしょうか？

Answer (score 1):

`DataTemplate`なのですから、まずは`DataContext`から`BindingBase`を使用してプロパティを操作するべきかと思います。

```
textBlock.SetBinding(TextBlock.TextProperty, new Binding("バインドするプロパティ"));
```

またイベントハンドラーを使用することもできます

```
imageElement.AddHandler(FrameworkElement.LoadedEvent, (RoutedEventHandler)imageElement_Loaded);

static void imageElement_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var imageElement = (Image)sender;
    // 何らかの処理
}
```

Comment: アドバイスをいただき、試行錯誤しているのですが、バインディングの理解が浅くうまくいっていない状態になります。たとえばなのですが、Buttonクラスなどを継承したクラスの中でDataTemplateに対し質問内容のようなコードで設定した場合、”テキスト本文"やイメージをバインディング可能なのでしょうか？（説明下手で済みません…）「DataContextからBindingBase」このあたりについてももっと調べてみます。

Comment: `Button`継承クラス内で`DataTemplate`を操作するというユースケースがしっくりこないのですが、前提として`DataTemplate`は`DataContext`とともにコントロールの使用者側に指定させるべきものです。単純にカスタムコントロールが自身の見た目を変更したいといった程度の話であれば、スタイルで`Template`プロパティを指定するのが妥当です。